# How to use ArcGIS dynamiclayer

Tags: arcgis-server, layers

I want to display separate layers from this ArcGIS Server with LeafletJS from this server https://gis.blm.gov/arcgis/rest/services/lands/BLM_Natl_SMA_Cached_with_PriUnk/MapServer

I can display all layers as raster tiles in Leaflet with this link
[https://gis.blm.gov/arcgis/rest/services/lands/BLM_Natl_SMA_Cached_without_PriUnk/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}](https://gis.blm.gov/arcgis/rest/services/lands/BLM_Natl_SMA_Cached_without_PriUnk/MapServer/tile/%7Bz%7D/%7By%7D/%7Bx%7D)

But I want to display only `US Forest Service (USFS)`. Is it possible to display it as a raster tile?

As I understand I need to use dynamiclayer option. I tried to use generateKml, but it still returns all layers, despite I select only one.

Comment: Removed tag Leaflet since question itself is in no way connected with Leaflet.

Comment: Try https://gis.blm.gov/arcgis/rest/services/lands/BLM_Natl_SMA_Cached_with_PriUnk/MapServer/9. 9 is the index for US Forest Service. It's a polygon so not sure how you can display it as a raster.

Answer (score 1):

https://gis.blm.gov/arcgis/rest/services/lands/BLM_Natl_SMA_Cached_with_PriUnk/MapServer is a cached (sometimes called a tiled) service. Notice how the metadata says `Map Cache: true`. You cannot access a tiled service as a dynamic service.

You can however request each layer as features, and then use [L.esri.featureLayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/esri-leaflet/layers/).